All elements in App.vue are automatically centered
I am creating my first Vue project with Vue3 and ts. But I found any kind of elements writen in the App.vue will be automatically centered in the screen, when the width of page is bigger than 1024.

<template> <div> <p>This is the App component</p> </div> </template>
I changed the version of Vue, change the code in App.vue but the problem still exists.
Also I copied the css,ts and vue files from other projects, problem still.
main.ts:
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import * as ElementPlusIconsVue from '@element-plus/icons-vue'

const app = createApp(App)

for (const [key, component] of Object.entries(ElementPlusIconsVue)) {
  app.component(key, component)
}

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(ElementPlus)
app.mount('#app')



Share the code please, but I'm pretty sure you are still loading the default style that comes with new Vue apps, double-check your main.ts

Probably some CSS flexbox defaults yes. Override it to your liking if you do not like it.

browser devtools should include styles when inspecting an element.  you may want to become more familiar with this powerful debugging tool.  you just need to search the elements of your app to find which one has styling on it controlling the centering of your other elements.  it will also tell you what stylesheet each CSS style comes from, and relevant classnames you can use to override in your code.
